# `chmod: missing operand` in bash xargs script

Tags: bash

I have a folder in centos 7 as below:

```
[root@localhost www]# ls -all
-rw-r--r--  1   apache websites     191 Apr 23  2018 robots.txt
drwxrwx---  3 websites websites      38 May 14  2018 functions
```

I want to change this these folders and files permissions to:

```
[root@localhost www]# ls -all
-r--------  1   apache apache     191 Apr 23  2018 robots.txt
drx-------  3   apache apache      38 May 14  2018 functions
```

I tried bash script as below:

```
find . -group websites -type f -print0 | tee >(xargs -0 chgrp apache) | xargs -0 chown apache | xargs -0 chmod 400
find . -group websites -type d -print0 | tee >(xargs -0 chgrp apache) | xargs -0 chown apache | xargs -0 chmod 500
```

But I get error :

```
chmod: missing operand after ‘400’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
chmod: missing operand after ‘500’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
```

What's the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `xargs -0 chown apache` consumes `tee`'s output and leaves nothing to `xargs -0 chmod 400`. Try `find . -group websites -type f -print0 | tee >(xargs -0 chown apache:apache) | xargs -0 chmod 400`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy,who not add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Letting `find` Do The Work

A simpler solution might look like:

```
find . -group websites \
  -exec chown apache:apache -- {} + \
  -exec chmod u=rX,g=,o= -- {} +
```

Because we're using `u=rX`, which sets `+x` only for directories or files that were already executable, we can do this only with one `find` command that doesn't filter on type at all.

The pattern as a whole works because `-exec ... {} +` adds as many arguments as possible to each command invoked, just as `xargs` does; using it, you don't need `xargs` at all, and so you also don't need `tee` to split into multiple `xargs` commands

---

#### Making The `tee` Solution Work

The problem with your original solution is that you were piping from `xargs -0 chown apache` to `xargs -0 chmod`. Because `chown`, and thus `xargs -0 chown`, writes no output to stdout, the `xargs -0 chmod` never received any input.

When you want to write to more than two processes from `tee`, use process substitutions for *all but the last* (or even all of them, and then redirect stdout to `/dev/null`, if you care more about consistency than a tiny bit of speed).

Thus:

```
tee >(xargs -0 chgrp apache) >(xargs -0 chown apache) | xargs -0 chmod 400
```

...or...

```
tee >(xargs -0 chgrp apache) >(xargs -0 chown apache) >(xargs -0 chmod 400) >/dev/null
```

(but it's silly to run both `chgrp` and `chown` as separate commands when you could `chown apache:apache` to set both ownership and group at once; also, it's preferable to use `--` as an end-of-options sigil before appending an unknown set of filenames as arguments -- doing so ensures that arguments starting with dashes will be treated as filenames, not as options).

Answer (score 3):

Why complicate things using multiple levels of indirection using `|` and `tee` when you can just run a loop over the result of `find` as below

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    chgrp apache "$file"
    chown apache "$file"
    chmod 400 "$file"
done < <(find . -group websites -type f -print0)
```

and for directories as below

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do
    chgrp apache "$dir"
    chown apache "$dir"
    chmod 500 "$dir"
done < <(find . -group websites -type d -print0)
```

You could very well combine this into one by just introducing a conditional to check for a directory on the result of `find`

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' content ; do
    chgrp apache "$content"
    chown apache "$content"
    [[ -d $content ]] && chmod 500 "$content" || chmod 400 "$content"
done < <(find . -group websites -print0)
```

---

As for the error you are seeing, your `tee`'s output is consumed by the `xargs` involving `chown` and it is not available beyond that, because it is not `tee`-ed out (made available in standard output) for the last level of `xargs`. To make it available make an another level of pass

```
find . -group websites -type f -print0 | tee >(xargs -0 chgrp apache) | tee >(xargs -0 chown apache) | xargs -0 chmod 400
```

---

Or even more better, just use `xargs -0` once and run the set of commands in one shot in a sub-shell

```
find . -group websites -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' sh -c 'chgrp apache "{}"; chown apache "{}"; chmod 400 "{}"'
```

As suggested by [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) in the comments, the above approach is **potentially vulnerable** as we substitute the filenames into script text, rather than passing them as separate arguments on the command line. The approach could be modified the following way (his suggestion)

```
find . -group websites -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c 'for f; do chgrp apache "$f"; chown apache "$f"; chmod 400 "$f"; done' _
```